# How to decrypt encrypted password in localStorage using javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, cryptography

I am using localStorage to store data and i want to encrypt the password, then when the password is encrypted in the localStorage i want now to decrypt it to be able to log-in. And i try the encryption is working but the decryption is not working and error message is: 
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input**

I am using CryptoJS v3.1.2 
code.google.com/p/crypto-js

here the code:

```
var JsonFormatter = {
stringify: function (cipherParams) {
var jsonObj = {ct: cipherParams.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)};
    if (cipherParams.iv) {jsonObj.iv = cipherParams.iv.toString();}
    if (cipherParams.salt) {jsonObj.s = cipherParams.salt.toString();}
    return JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
},
 parse: function (jsonStr) {
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
    var cipherParams = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
        ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(jsonObj.ct)
    });
    if (jsonObj.iv) {cipherParams.iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(jsonObj.iv)}
    if (jsonObj.s) {cipherParams.salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(jsonObj.s)}
    return cipherParams;
}
};
```

encryption.js

```
function btnSubmit(){

var p = document.getElementById("setpass").value;
if(p.length >= 5){

    var password = localStorage["Password"];
    var encoded = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(p), password, {format: JsonFormatter}).ciphertext.toString();
    localStorage.setItem("Password", encoded);

    jAlert('Password is set', 'URIBlocker');
        window.location.reload();
}
else
{
    //Notification
} 
}
```

decrypt.js

```
function login() {

var usepass = document.getElementById('usepass').value;

var password = localStorage["Password"];
var encrypted = localStorage.getItem("Password");
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, password, {formatter: JsonFormatter}).toString();
var secret = JSON.parse(decrypted);


if (usepass === secret)
 {                          
    $('.bd_class').show();
    $('.go_class').hide();
 }
 else
 {
    $('.bd_class').hide();
    $('go_class').show();

}
}
```

Something is wrong and i don't know the error is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: For starters your `login` function is missing a `}` in the code you posted, maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Sorry i forgot the } but still not working

Comment: What file is the `SyntaxError` coming from?

Comment: Is there an easy way to do the encryption and decryption for password authentication thanks.

Comment: the syntax error is on the code (var secret = JSON.parse(decrypted);) it say Unexpected end of input

Comment: Please see this article: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/